# C#: the 1st send of tcp client is ok but not the 2nd one

Tags: c#, tcp, client

I'm trying to write my first simple C# client application on Visual Studio (my server app is written in Python and is running on Linux). My client is connected and I have defined a StreamReader (STR) and a StreamWriter (STW) on client.GetStream(). STW.AutoFlush property is set to True. A click event on my Send button catches the text I write in my textbox. The  text entered is sent to the server via STW.WriteLine and the answer is received via STR.ReadLine(). The result is displayed in another text box.

The first pass is ok: text is sent and answer is received and displayed. When I try to enter a second text, it does not seem to be sent to the server. I don't know why. Code follows:

```
private void Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rtbRequest.Text != "") {
            text_to_send = rtbRequest.Text;
            STW.WriteLine(text_to_send);
            receive = STR.ReadLine();
            this.rtbResult.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { rtbResult.AppendText(receive); }));
            //client.Close();
            //client = new TcpClient();
            //client.Connect(IP_End);
            //STW = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
            //STR = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
            //STW.AutoFlush = true;
        }
    }
```

If in the click event I close the client after each send, reopen a connection and redefine STW and STR, it works (commented lines above). Any idea why?

Regards,
Patrick

EDIT: full implementation of STR and STW as requested by Nicolas:

```
        client = new TcpClient();
        IP_End = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"), 13773);
        try
        {
            client.Connect(IP_End);
            if (client.Connected)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connected to server");
                STW = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
                STR = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                STW.AutoFlush = true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x.Message.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: A few ideas: add try/catch to see if there is any exception, and use debug to follow your second try. Also, try to manually flush your STW after each line written

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. An exception occurs on the second STR.Readline: {"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine."}. That explains why it works when I reopen the connection. But I don't understand why the connection is aborted after the first time.

Comment: Add the full implementation of your client (how the STR STW are managed for example) to see if we can help you